# Recursive call create a stackOverflow

Tags: java, recursion, huffman-code

I came to ask for your help, I did a school a project asking us to create an Huffman program, everything was fine until now... My problem is that my recursive function in charge of decoding my text seems to be pretty bad because it give me a stackOverflow after ~3500 recursion in order to build a long text. I tried a lot of thing but I can't figured an idea to solve the main problem which seems to be the number of recursion. I'll show you my main functions here.

Here is the encoding one :

```java
    public static String codeText(String textString, HashMap<String, String> tableCode) {
        if(textCode.isEmpty()) {
            return textCode;
        }

        String encode = ""; // Final code   
        String[] lineSplit = texteString.split(""); // I use a string so I need to split it
        for (String element : lineSplit) { 
            if (tableCode.containsKey(element)) {
                encode += tableCode.get(element.toLowerCase());//I use lower case cause I don't know how to detect the capitals
            } else {
                encode += tableCode.get("?"); // If the char isn't in our huffman tree
            }
        }
        return encode;
    }
```

Now the main problem, I really don't know how to make it differently

```java
    // Launcher to build our arrayOfString
    public static String decodeText(Node huffman, Node huffmanFull, String textCode) {
        String textDecode = ""; //Final text
        ArrayList<String> arrayOfCode = new ArrayList<>(); //Code split into an array
        String[] textSplit = textCode.split("");
        
        for (String element : textSplit) {
            arrayOfCode.add(element);
        }
        
        return decodeText2(huffman, huffmanFull, arrayOfCode, textDecode);
    }

    public static String decodeText2(Node huffman, Node huffmanFull, ArrayList<String> arrayOfCode, Node textDecode) {
        if (huffman.vide()) {
            return textDecode;
        }

        if (arrayOfCode.size() == 0) {
            textDecode += huffman.getData();// We add the last char
            return textDecode;
        }

        if (huffman.getData() == null) { // We travel arround the tree in order to find the associate char
            if (arrayOfCode.get(0).equals("0")) { // if the code is 0 go left child
                arrayOfCode.remove(0); //we remove the actual index
                
                return decodeText2(huffman.left(), huffmanFull, arrayOfCode, textDecode);
            } else if (arrayOfCode.get(0).equals("1")) {// 1 we go right
                arrayOfCode.remove(0);
                
                return decodeText2(huffman.right(), huffmanFull, arrayOfCode, textDecode);
            }
        } else {
            the char from the code has been found
            textDecode += huffman.getData() ; // we add it to the string
            return decodeText2(huffman = huffmanFull, huffmanFull, arrayOfCode, textDecode); // We reset the huffman tree with the full one
        }

        return textDecode;
    }
```

I hope it's clear enough, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Given a large enough problem, all recursions (in Java) will eventually end up in a `StackOverflowError`. That is the nature of the beast. If we wanted to avoid this problem entirely, we would have to rewrite the code as iteration, not recursion.

Comment: I wish I could, it's a pain to work with recursive but it's what our teacher wants. And I've exhausted all my ideas, cause right now to code is about 14000 char and overflow way too soon

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that last call to `decodeText2()`. Your instructor wants you to use recursion to decode *one* Huffman code, which you are doing with the first two recursive calls of `decodeText2()`. You should use a *loop* to call that recursive routine to decode the sequence of Huffman codes. You should not be using recursion to loop over all of the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It has solved everything, it's way easier like that.